# Chart.js: Updating chart shows wrong time format for a while

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm collecting data in two arrays: one for values and one for timestamps.

For every new couple of data collected the chart is updated.

I would like to use a specific time format for labels, but for the first updates the time format is wrong.

This is the format I expected:

```
'HH:mm:ss'
```

Here an example:

https://codepen.io/mandria/pen/zYjVWGa

It seems to be somehow related to the resolution: smaller resolutions show correct format earlier.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, I think what you'll want to do is to set the following `displayFormats` explicitly.

```js
displayFormats: {
  millisecond: "HH:mm:ss",
  second: "HH:mm:ss",
  minute: "HH:mm:ss",
  hour: "HH:mm:ss",
  day: "MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
  week: "MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
  month: "MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
  quarter: "MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
  year: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
}
```

That way, when the X-axis is on millisecond resolution, it will display `HH:mm:ss`.  I've left a couple of the buckets set to different display styles to demonstrate how you can adjust the format as the resolution of the X-axis changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is that the correct time format is shown only after many updates, and it's wrong at the beginning.  If you look at the linked example you'll see that time is shown as 4:41:56.257 AM, and after some updates the same time is finally shown as 16:41:56, that is the expected result.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, you must set ALL of the display formats--not just one of them.  In my example, the format should be `HH:mm:ss` until the X-Axis resolution reaches days, at which point the format would change to `MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (I will update the example to make that more clear).